# Защита от скачивания картинок в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php

Нашел скрипт для `.htaccess` для защиты от использования картинок на чужом сайте,
но почему-то этот скрипт не работает и не выдает картинку `steal.jpg`. Вот пример `http://www.draw-art.ru/photoshop/nature/14/2.jpg`. Создал html страничку на компе с этим адресом и выводилась эта страница.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
#Запрещаем загрузку файлов с внешних сайтов
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?draw-art.ru/ [nc]
RewriteRule .*.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://draw-art.ru/img/steal.jpg[nc]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь что у вас работает Rewrite. Например напишите самый простой скрипт, что то вроде:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .*jpg$ /1.php [L]
```

1.php разместите в корне сайта. 
Если rewrite настроен то вместо jpg файлов должно отображаться содержимое 1.php

**upd:**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?draw-art.ru/ [nc]
RewriteRule .*.(gif|jpg|png)$ /img/steal.jpg [nc]
```

У меня работает ...

Comment: да теперь  отображает страницу 1.php

Comment: а что теперь делать =)

Answer (score 0):

Хммм точку не экранировали?

```
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://draw-art.ru/img/steal.jpg [nc]
```

обратите внимание на "**\.**" и пробел перед "**[nc]**"

Comment: нет не помогло (